# Angular 6 unit testing with HttpTestingController with pipe(map())

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine, angular-httpclient

In my unit test (with Jasmine), there is this service that is something like this:

```
getData() {    
    OtherService.getProtocol().pipe(
          map((protocol) => {
            this.protocol = protocol;
            return this.http.get(path);
          }))
}
```

Now in order to test this, I mock the otherService with following:

```
otherService = jasmine.createSpyObj('OtherService', ['getProtocol']);
otherService.getProtocol.and.returnValue(of(fakeValue));
```

And this part is verified working correctly.

However during unit test, I can not catch the http request made inside `map()` even by calling `.verify()` directly

```
describe('DeeplinkService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let otherService;
  let myService: MyService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    otherService = jasmine.createSpyObj('OtherService', ['getProtocol']);
    otherService.getProtocol.and.returnValue(of(fakeValue));
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        MyService,
        { provide: OtherService, useValue: otherService },
      ]
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    myService = injector.get(MyService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('fake test', () => {
      myService.getData().subscribe();
      httpMock.verify();  // <== Pass w/o fail
    }
  );

});
```

Any idea what went wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Specify the return type of your method. You'll realize that it returns an Observable<Observable<Object>>. I really doubt that's what you want. Read about mergeMap() / switchMap().

Comment: Thank you JB!! I actually realized it right after I posted the question...